# How to retrieve a Mongo document based on the value of an element in a List field with Python

Tags: python, list, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection with documents that have a text field and list field :

```
db = client.PraxisDB
db.create_collection('Test')
```

I enter three documents into it

```
kollection = db.Test
kollection.insert_one({'text1': 'aaa','list1' : [' ',1,2,3,4]})    
kollection.insert_one({'text1': 'bbb','list1' : [' ',1,6,7,8]})      
kollection.insert_one({'text1': 'ccc','list1' : [' ',19,10,11,12]})
```

I can see that all are properly inserted

```
c = kollection.find()
for crnt in c:
    print(crnt)
---
{'_id': ObjectId('61e543057aeccaf5a5345073'), 'text1': 'aaa', 'list1': [' ', 1, 2, 3, 4]}
{'_id': ObjectId('61e543057aeccaf5a5345074'), 'text1': 'bbb', 'list1': [' ', 1, 6, 7, 8]}
{'_id': ObjectId('61e543057aeccaf5a5345075'), 'text1': 'ccc', 'list1': [' ', 19, 10, 11, 12]}
```

I can retrieve individual records ONLY IF i specify the whole list

```
c = kollection.find({'list1': {'$eq': [' ',1, 2, 3, 4]}},{'_id':0})
for crnt in c:
    print(crnt)
-----
{'text1': 'aaa', 'list1': [' ', 1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

I wish to retrieve the two docs that have value of 1 in the second element of the list field. For this I tried :

```
c = kollection.find({'list1'[1]: {'$eq': 1}},{})
for crnt in c:
    print(crnt)
```

This query returned no documents. How should I change my query? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do this.

```
c = kollection.find({'list1.1': {'$eq': 1}},{'_id':0})
for crnt in c:
    print(crnt)
-----
{'text1': 'aaa', 'list1': [' ', 1, 2, 3, 4]}
{'text1': 'bbb', 'list1': [' ', 1, 6, 7, 8]}
```

Should have been obvious! But it wasnt to me